# Dynamically loading jar as library for other classes

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I am developing a plugin system for a web server application and have run into a problem with plugins that require external libraries (jars not native ones). Because of the way I load the plugins (after the application is starts) I cannot find a way to dynamically load these jar libraries for use by the plugin.

Plugins are compiled as jars and must contain a file in the jar called plugin.info. This file follows this format:

```
main=x.y.z.PluginMainClass (the main class of the plugin to be loaded and instantiated by the application - as shown below)
load-lib=jsocket.jar
load-class=com.jsocket.Server
load-class=com.jsocket.Client
```

This is the relevant part of how I would load a plugin:

```
JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(file);
Enumeration<JarEntry> e = jarFile.entries();

URL[] urls = { new URL("jar:file:" + file.getPath() + "!/") };
URLClassLoader cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls);

String pluginClass = "";
File loadLib = null;
URLClassLoader libLoader = null;

ArrayList<String> postLoad = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Class<?>> classes = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
    JarEntry je = (JarEntry) e.nextElement();
    if(je.isDirectory() || !je.getName().endsWith(".class")){
        if(je.getName().equals("plugin.info")){
            String dat = readStringFromJarEntry(je);
            for(String line : dat.split("\n")){
                String[] parts = line.split(Pattern.quote("="));
                if(parts.length < 2)continue;
                if(parts[0].equals("main"))
                    pluginClass = parts[1];
                else if(parts[0].equals("load-lib")){
                    File libFile = new File("./lib", parts[1]);
                    libLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] { new URL("jar:file:" + libFile.getPath() + "!/") });
                }else if(parts[0].equals("load-class")){
                    libLoader.loadClass(parts[1]);//Class<?> cls = Class.forName(parts[1], true, libLoader);//THIS WORKS FINE WITH NO EXCEPTIONS
                }
            }
        }
        continue;
    }
    String className = je.getName().substring(0, je.getName().length() - 6);
    postLoad.add(className);
}
//Load all classes in plugin jar
for(String className : postLoad){
    log.d("Loading plugin class " + className);
    className = className.replace('/', '.');
    Class<?> c = cl.loadClass(className);
    classes.add(c);
}
jarFile.close();
for(Class<?> cls : classes){
    if(cls.getCanonicalName().equals(pluginClass)){
        Object plug = cls.newInstance();
        if(plug instanceof IPlugin){
            IPlugin iplug = (IPlugin)plug;
            plugins.add(iplug);//plugins is an arraylist of objects implementing IPlugin
        }
    }
}
```

(Sorry for the lengthy code but it's necessary)

Here's a snippet of the main class of the plugin:

```
@Override
public void init(){
    Server server = new Server(1221);//Reference to Server class in jsocker lib (first arg is port)
}
```

As you can see, the plugin uses classes from the jsocket library. I have loaded the classes from the jsocket lib using `URLClassLoader#loadClass` but I get the following error when initializing the plugin:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jsocket/Server
```

How can I fix this and make the `URLClassLoader#loadClass` load classes to the classpath?

Comment: First, simply use File#toURI#toURL to get the jars up; second, if you jar has a manifest from file with a class-path entry, listing the dependencies, they will be loaded automatically

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks for your reply. When I was using File#toURI#toURL, is gave a strange output with a path to the working directory and the the 'jar:file:lib/x.jar' which did not work. Also, the plugin's manifest will be ignored as it is not being loaded traditionally. Instead I attempt to load the classes directly. If you are talking about the application's jar, I cannot add the dependencies of the plugins as the idea of plugins is that they are loaded dynamically.

Comment: With regards to the manifest file, yes, I just include a MANIFEST.MF file in my jars, I then use a "entry" configuration file, like you are, to describe the plugin, saves on a lot of coding

Comment: If File#toURI#toURL is giving you a strange result, then there is a problem with where the hat files are located or how you're referencing them

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'll have another look at File#toURI#toURL. My jar file is being loaded with the code above and all the classes are successfully 'loaded' also but they are not specified on the classpath so cannot be used by any other classes which have already been loaded.

Comment: If the classes were "loaded" properly, we would be having this discussion ;)

Comment: I suppose :) @MadProgrammer - What I mean is that no ClassNotFoundException is thrown until I try to run Class.forName on the main class.

Comment: That's because no classes are actually loaded until you do (`Class.forName`), instead, you're just setting up the "search" parameters which the `ClassLoader` will use to resolve a class by name